# How to add same column to multiple tables in a DB and fill it with a constant value?

Tags: php, database, postgresql

I have a database with multiple tables. I want to add a new column to each one of them and fill these column with some constant integer value. My search on google did not give me desired answer.

I am using PostgreSQL and PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you use ALTER TABLE to create a new column and SET  DEFAULT to set the default value to all column fields?

Like:

ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN mynumber integer;
ALTER mynumber SET DEFAULT 7

(http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-altertable.html)

Comment: you are right, but this is for one table and I have around 100 tables and 20 such databases, so to do it manually will be tedious. I am wondering if this whole process can be automated?